# Как организовать нормали для куба заданного вершинами и индексами?

Tags: opengl, шейдеры, opengles, glsl

Как правильно организовать нормали для освещения куба?

1. Вершины куба:

   ```
   std::vector<Vertex> vertices = {
           Vertex {Position: glm::vec3(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)},
           Vertex {Position: glm::vec3(-0.5,  0.5, -0.5)},
           Vertex {Position: glm::vec3( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5)},
           Vertex {Position: glm::vec3( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5)},
           Vertex {Position: glm::vec3(-0.5, -0.5,  0.5)},
           Vertex {Position: glm::vec3(-0.5,  0.5,  0.5)},
           Vertex {Position: glm::vec3( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5)},
           Vertex {Position: glm::vec3( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5)}};
   ```
2. Индексы куба:

   ```
   std::vector<unsigned int> indices = {
           0, 1, 2,  0, 2, 3, // front
           4, 5, 6,  4, 6, 7, // back
           0, 1, 5,  0, 5, 4, // left
           2, 6, 3,  3, 6, 7, // right
           1, 5, 2,  2, 5, 6, // up
           9, 4, 3,  3, 4, 7  // bottom
   };
   ```
3. Рисование куба осуществляется через метод drawElements

Если я правильно понял теорию... то для расчета цвета на каждую вершину куба должно приходиться по 3 нормали, что видно из [рисунка](https://gamedev.ru/files/images/cube_norm.png).

Но я не могу понять, как мне передавать в шейдер 3 нормали для одной вершины?

А в случае, если передать всё же получится, как определить нормаль, которая нужна для текущей грани? (т.к. у нас 3 нормали на одну вершину)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вам нужно разделить вершины**

Т.к. для каждой стороны куба нормаль должна быть своя, и ее нельзя хранить нигде, кроме как в атрибутах вершины, вам придется "разделить" ваш куб на 6 сторон по 4 вершины (и 2 треугольника). Соответственно у вас должно быть 24 вершины, с совпадающими позициями и различающимися нормалями, и 12 треугольников использующих их.

На вашем рисунке все верно изображено - просто для наглядности стороны куба немного разнесены.

P.S. Разделение вершин это стандартная практика, которая также необходима для "разорваных" UV разверток и стыков различных материалов.